# Empty response when trying to fetch mock data from Service

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes, dynamic-routing

I want to fetch and display data from Array of Objects.
I have created the parameterized routes.

**1. app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'all-trades',
    component: AllTradesComponent,

  }, 
  { 
    path: 'crop/:name', component: CropComponent 

}]
```

**2. Crop.ts**

```
export class Crop {
    name: string;
    checked: boolean;
    subCategory: Subcategory[];
}

export class Subcategory {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    isActive: boolean;
}
```

**3. CropData.ts**

Here is my Array of object, I want to access subCategory and display the **name** on webpage.
for example: When user click on Rice then its should get the result like **'Basmati', 'Ammamore'**
**OR**
When user click on Wheat then its should get the result like **'Durum', 'Emmer'**
**OR**
When user click on Barley then its should get the result like **'Hulless Barley', 'Barley Flakes'**

```
import { Crop } from './Crop';

export const CROP: Crop[] = [
    {
        name: 'Rice',
        checked: true,
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Basmati',
                isActive: true,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Ammamore',
                isActive: true,
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Wheat',
        checked: true,
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Durum',
                isActive: true,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Emmer',
                isActive: true,
            },
        ],
    }, {
        name: 'Barley',
        checked: true,
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'Hulless Barley',
                isActive: true,
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: 'Barley Flakes',
                isActive: true,
            },
        ],
    }
]
```

**4.1 crop.service.ts**
// First I tried this logic

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { skipWhile } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Crop } from '../shared/Crop';
import { CROP } from '../shared/cropdata';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CropService {

  constructor() { }

  CropData: Crop
  getCrop(name: string): Crop {
    return this.CropData.filter((crop) => (crop.name === name))[0];


  }
}
```

**4.2 crop.service.ts**
// Then I tried this logic

```
export class CropService {
private selectedCrop= new BehaviorSubject<Crop>(null);

setCrop(crop:Crop){
 this.selectedCrop.next(crop);
 }

getCrop(){
this.selectedCrop.asObservable().pipe(skipWhile(val=> val === null)); 
}
}
```

I failed in both the cases.

**5.1 all-trades.components.ts**

// First tried using function

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Crop } from 'src/app/shared/Crop';
import { CropService } from '../crop.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-trades',
  templateUrl: './all-trades.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-trades.component.css'],
})
export class AllTradesComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor(private service: CropService, private router: Router) { }

// Here I tried to make use of function but still its doesnot giving me the desire result

onSelect(selectedCrop:Crop){
this.service.setCrop(selectedCrop);
this.router.navigateByUrl(`crop/${crop.name}`);
}


  onChange(event, index, item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
    console.log(index, event, item);
  }



  ngOnInit(): void { }

  
}
```

5.1 all-trades-component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div
  fxLayout="row"
  fxLayout.lt-md="column"
  fxLayoutAlign="space-between start"
  fxLayoutAlign.lt-md="start stretch"
>
  <div class="container-outer" fxFlex="20">
    <div class="filters">
      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select Crop</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let crop of crops">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="crop.checked"
                (change)="onChange($event, i, crop)"
              >
                {{ crop.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>

      
  <div class="content container-outer" fxFlex="80">
    <mat-card
      class="crop-card"
      style="min-width: 17%"
      *ngFor="let crop of crops"
      [hidden]="!crop.checked"
    >
   
<!-- here i call the function -->
        <a (click)="onSelect(crop)" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"> 
        <mat-card-header>
          <img
            mat-card-avatar
            class="example-header-image"
            src="/assets/icons/crops/{{ crop.name }}.PNG"
            alt="crop-image"
          />
          <mat-card-title>{{ crop.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>100 Kgs</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
      </a>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>PRICE</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

6. crop-componet.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Crop } from 'src/app/shared/Crop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-crop',
  templateUrl: './crop.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crop.component.css']
})
export class CropComponent implements OnInit {
  service: any;
  crop: any;
  route: any;
  cropservice: any;
  sub: Subscription;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // let name = this.route.snapshot.params['name'];
    // this.crop = this.cropservice.getCrop(name);
    this.sub = this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
      let name = params.get("name")
      this.crop = this.cropservice.getCrop(name)
    })
  }

}
```

**7. crop-component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let category of crop.subCategory">{{category.id}}</div>
```

This is my eniter code I dont know where I am going wrong please help in fetching data from arrays of object.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
**This is my all-trades.component.html output**

1. When I click Rice I get this as output (Url get change )

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

2. When I click Wheat I get this

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

And so on....
I just want to display the name of subCategory Array.
Please give me the solution.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxdyj.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOAtc.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVcfT.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your **4.1** you seem to forget to assign your mock data into your variable

```
....

import { CROP } from '../shared/cropdata';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CropService {

  constructor() { }

  CropData: Crop[] = CROP;        // Assign the value


  getCrop(name: string): Crop {
    return this.CropData.filter((crop) => (crop.name === name))[0];
  }
}
```

On your **4.2**, you forgot to assign your mock data as well in your BehaviorSubject if you end up using this method. BehaviorSubjects are known to emit initial data

```
...

import { CROP } from '../shared/cropdata';


export class CropService {

private selectedCrop = new BehaviorSubject<Crop[]>(CROP);   // Pass CROP mock data

    setCrop(crop: Crop[]) {
      this.selectedCrop.next(crop);
    }

    getCrop() {
      this.selectedCrop.asObservable().pipe(skipWhile(val=> val === null)); 
    }

}
```

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-crop-sample?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference. You can check the `console` for the response

Comment: After editing its giving me error (property) CropService.CropData: Crop
Type 'Crop[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Crop': name, checked, subCategoryts(2739)

Comment: Can you please provide me the similar kind of example on stackblitz, I want to access the names under subCategory array.... I am very confused now... Not getting it... or if not then can you please modify my code .... that would really kind of you... please

Comment: @faisalmoinuddin Have updated the answer above. Since your Mock Data interface is Crop[] based on your CropData.ts, you also need to assign your variables containing them in service to also with type Crop[]. May I know if this works on your side?

Comment: Have created a Stackblitz demo for your reference. Have updated the answer above. You can check the console on the attached stackblitz. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hey KShewengger, I really appreciate your effort but its still doesnt work out for me... Please suggest me something different, what would you have done if you were in my situation. Can you please tell your approach....

Comment: I have a list of crops in my all-trades.html, Like -> Rice then Wheat, and Barley. Now If I click on Rice its should go into the Rice Array and fetch the names of all sub-category Array and display the names on different page.. and similary for wheat and Barley as well... Please help me

Comment: Hi, I have updated the Stackblitz demo based on your preferences. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I got it now.... Thanks alot  KShewengger you made my day...... Thanks alot from my bottom of my heart ..... If you dont mind can you please share your stack overflow link so that in future whenever I stuck some where you will guid me ... if you dont mind then only how should i text you ?

Comment: Hi @faisalmoinuddin, no problem. Glad I can help. It would also help if you could upvote my answer and mark it as the accepted answer, that would mean a lot! thank you very much! No worries, if you have encountered some problem, a lot of Stackoverflow users will help you too, including me. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Yeah Done ! Once again Thanks 

Comment: Hey @KShewengger ! Hope you and your family are doing great, actually I stuck once again, its related to your solution so I thought to ask you . I am sharing the link of my problem. Hope you wont mind.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64892181/i-want-to-add-filter-in-my-array-of-object-i-do-not-want-duplicate-check-box/64893493#64893493