# I want to add filter in my array of object.... I do not want duplicate check boxes with same same

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox, filtering

**My webpage :**

[image]

Here you can see on left hand side I have set of checkboxes but also there are **some repeated names** which I **dont want**, Here you can see **Rice is repeated twice but I want it should display only Once** . After checking Rice checkbox its should display all the cards which have name as Rice but different District name. Here I want filtering.

Also I am sharing my code base with you guys please help me.

**1. crop.model.ts**

```
export class Crop {
    name: string;
    checked: boolean;
    district: string
    subCategory: Subcategory[];
}

export class Subcategory {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    checked: boolean;
}
```

**2. crop.data.ts**

```
import { Crop } from "./crop.model";

export const CROPS: Crop[] = [
    {
        name: "Rice",    // I want this Rice 
        checked: true,
        district: "Thane",
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Basmati",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Ammamore",
                checked: true
            }
        ]
    }, {
        name: "Rice",  // also this one but on clicking on single Checkbox with name as Rice
        checked: true,
        district: "Nashik ",
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Basmati",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Ammamore",
                checked: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Wheat",
        checked: true,
        district: "Nashik",
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Durum",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Emmer",
                checked: true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "Barley",
        checked: true,
        district: "Ratnagiri",
        subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Hulless Barley",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Barley Flakes",
                checked: true
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

**3. crop.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";

import { Crop } from "../shared/crop.model";
import { CROPS } from "../shared/crop.data";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CropService {
  constructor() { }

  crops: Crop[] = CROPS;

  getAllCrops(): Observable<Crop[]> {
    return of(this.crops);
  }

  getCrop(name: string): Observable<any> {
    const crop = this.crops.filter(crop => crop.name === name)[0];

    return of(crop);
  }
}
```

**4. all-trades.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div
  fxLayout="row"
  fxLayout.lt-md="column"
  fxLayoutAlign="space-between start"
  fxLayoutAlign.lt-md="start stretch"
>
  <div class="container-outer" fxFlex="20">
    <div class="filters">
      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select Crop</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let crop of crops$ | async">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="crop.checked"
                (change)="onChange($event, i, crop)"
              >
                {{ crop.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>

      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select District</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let crop of crops$ | async">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="crop.checked"
                (change)="onChange($event, i, crop)"
              >
                {{ crop.district }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content container-outer" fxFlex="80">
    <mat-card
      class="crop-card"
      style="min-width: 17%"
      *ngFor="let crop of crops$ | async"
      [hidden]="!crop.checked"
    >
      <a [routerLink]="[crop.name]">
        <mat-card-header>
          <img
            mat-card-avatar
            class="example-header-image"
            src="/assets/icons/crops/{{ crop.name }}.PNG"
            alt="crop-image"
          />
          <mat-card-title>{{ crop.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>100 Kgs</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
      </a>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>PRICE</p>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>{{ crop.district }}</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

**5. all-trades.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Crop } from 'src/app/shared/crop.model';
import { CropService } from '../crop.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-trades',
  templateUrl: './all-trades.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-trades.component.css'],
})
export class AllTradesComponent implements OnInit {

  crops$: Observable<Crop[]>;

  constructor(private cropService: CropService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.crops$ = this.cropService.getAllCrops();
  }
  onChange(event, index, item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
    console.log(index, event, item);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better structure of your crop data according to your need would be :-

**crop.data.ts**

```
import { Crop } from "./crop.model";

export const CROPS: Crop[] = [
    {
        name: "Rice",    // I want this Rice 
        checked: true,
        crops: [{
            district: "Thane",
            subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Basmati",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Ammamore",
                checked: true
            }]
         }, 
         {
            district: "Nashik",
            subCategory: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: "Basmati",
                checked: true
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                name: "Ammamore",
                checked: true
            }]
         }
    },
    {
        name: "Wheat",
        checked: true,
        crops: [{
            district: "Nashik",
            subCategory: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Durum",
                    checked: true
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Emmer",
                    checked: true
                }
            ]
        }]
    },
    {
        name: "Barley",
        checked: true,
        crops: [{
            district: "Ratnagiri",
            subCategory: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Hulless Barley",
                    checked: true
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Barley Flakes",
                    checked: true
                }
            ]
        }]   
     }
 ];
```

Also you can keep districts array instead of districts field if subcategories for a particular crops are always same. Else you can go for this approach which i have shown. And You UI can be modiefied according to crops data i have shared accordingly.

Comment: Hey @Abhijeet thanx for taking this much effort, bro but can you please modify my interface class as well because its showing me error